# Query table and return values with the highest confidence only and remove duplicates

Tags: sql

I want to find a Microsoft SQL query to only get the maximum customer_confidence for a specific customer.

[image]

**Scenario 1**
In the example table you will see that number `454` for customer `2603396` has two confidence percentages, one at `75%` and one at `50%`, I would only like the `75%` to be returned.

**Scenario 2**
For number `918` I have two customer numbers `2744398` and `4866968`, I only want the highest customer_confidence customer result to be returned, in the example table it should be `2744398` with `75%` confidence.

How can I achieve this in Microsoft SQL?

Here is what I have tried:

```
select 
        distinct no, customer
        ,max(customer_confidence) as 'customer_confidence'
from (Table)
```

Comment: What query have you tried?

Comment: select 
  distinct no, customer
  ,max(customer_confidence) as 'customer_confidence'
from Table